# Fastest way to get nearest geometry to a point in GeoDjango

Tags: python, django, geodjango

I've got a large number of points (~1.5 million) in the WGS84 coordinate system. The points span a large area, so I can't use a projected coordinate system. I want to find the closest point to a given pair of input coordinates. I have a working view, but it takes too long (~2.5 seconds) to execute.

This is my model:

```
from django.contrib.gis.db import models

class Point(models.Model):

    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    geom = models.PointField(srid=4326, spatial_index=True)

    objects = models.GeoManager()
```

This is the query in the view (which I got from another SO question):

```
input_point = GEOSGeometry('POINT({0} {1})'.format(lon, lat))
point = Point.objects.distance(input_point).order_by('distance')[0]
```

Is there a way to do this faster? I have an equivalent query in SQLAlchemy/GeoAlchemy2, which takes less than 0.5 seconds to execute, so I know it's possible.

```
from geoalchemy2.elements import WKTElement

pt = WKTElement('POINT({0} {1})'.format(lon, lat), srid=4326)
q = session.query(Point).order_by(Point.geom.distance_box(pt)).first()
```

Is there a better way to do "nearest point" queries with GeoDjango?

Answer (score 4):

Not sure, this may be faster.  You can use the google projection (`900913`) to get your data in meters.

```
from django.contrib.gis.measure import D

DISTANCE_LIMIT_METERS = 5000

input_point = Point(lon, lat, srid=4326)
input_point.transform(900913)
ModelContainingPoint.objects.filter(geom__dwithin=(input_point , D(m=DISTANCE_LIMIT_METERS)))
```

Reference:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/gis/db-api/#distance-queries

Comment: Sorry about the lack of response. I tried this as well, but it was not faster. I also tried using the geography type instead of geometry, which was also suggested in the docs to be faster for distance queries, but it was actually much slower in my case. I ended up rewriting the app in Flask.

Comment: @bananafish i'm curious whats the result of moving to flask, how you solved your performance[speed] issue. It will be helpful for others as well. To me it seems making raw sql queries or writing callable procedures in postgresql should solve this issue, otherwise some separate api would be better rather than switching your whole app to other framework.

Comment: @ZubairAlam the move to Flask with GeoAlchemy was very successful for me, it has really good integration with PostGIS. I see your point though, it can certainly be argued that switching framework over this issue was a bit over the top, but it was quite early in development, so it was not as big of a hurdle as it might seem.