# Django- serialize attribute not in model

Tags: python, django, serialization, django-models, django-serializer

I'm trying to serialize a model with additional data. My model looks like this:

```
class Object(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False)
    lat = models.FloatField()
    lng = models.FloatField()
```

I'm passing in my latitude/longitude using HTML5/Ajax. When I get that I'm using a custom manager to calculate the distance to the current location:

```
class Object(models.Manager):

    def closest(self, lat, lng):
        from django.db import connection
        cursor = connection.cursor()
        cursor.execute("""
            SELECT a.*, SQRT(
            POW(69.1 * (a.lat - %s), 2) +
            POW(69.1 * (%s - a.lng) * COS(a.lat / 57.3), 2)) AS distance
            FROM app_object a
            GROUP BY a.id
            ORDER BY distance
        """ % (lat, lng))
        results = []
        for row in cursor.fetchall():
            p = self.model(id=row[0],name=row[1],description=row[2])
            p.distance = row[3]
            results.append(p)
        return results`
```

When I do results[0].distance, I get a distance. Back in my views, I serialize the results but only name, lat, and lng are in the "fields" section. If I pass "distance" into my serialize function like so:
    serialized_data = serializers.serialize('json', results, fields="distance")

the fields value is empty, suggesting "distance" is not in the model. Any idea what to do?

Thanks.

Comment: Doesn't help your question directly, but just in case you weren't aware:
1) There is a geospatial extension for django (see e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15915801/fastest-way-to-get-nearest-geometry-to-a-point-in-geodjango)
2) I'm going to hope the 69.1 / 57.3 magic numbers handle the mapping from euclidean 2d distance and spherical distance (on the other hand, if I'm not suffering too much from sleep dep, you should be able to drop the sqrt and the 69.1 and the sorting should still work but won't help if you want to use the distance)
3.  Can you just add a dummy distance field?

Comment: I've heard about GeoDjango but haven't looked into it too much. I tried adding a dummy distance field, but in order for it to return a distance after serializing I would have to save the distance to the database every time. I would definitely run into problems down the line.